# Count number of Children

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML like this,

```
<neededtools>
    <tool>3 mm</tool>
    <tool>6 mm</tool>
    <tool>9 mm</tool>
</neededtools>
```

My context node is `<tool>` . I would like to check if `<neededtool>` has more that 1 tool.

Ex: When when my context is `<tool>6 mm</tool>`, I want to return `TRUE` as parent of tool = neededtool has at least 1 child.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the context is one of the `tool` elements, you can use the following XPath expression to *return true if the parent contains more than one `tool`, and return false otherwise* :

```
count(../tool) > 1
```

You want to use `parent::*` or `parent::neededtools` to replace `..`, depending on your specific needs and personal preference.